# Visual basic - Questlon

Tags: vb.net

How would you have a button generate a number from 0-255 (randomly) then force it to display into a textbox in your form field? Also make it so it then counts the times you have clicked the button and have it force the text into a textbox?

Also how would you force a textbox so you can only input a number from 0-255.

Another question when you do "Application.Restart()" how do you force it to display as the top application (over all other programs running.) on reload.

Comment: I would open visual studio, then I would write some code, then if it didn't work I would post a question to stackoverflow.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ].  Do not ask multiple questions in a single post.  Please give your question a meaningful title.  And please try to make an effort to solve the problem yourself, posting code to illustrate what you've tried and what problems you've encountered.  Simply posting multiple questions and expecting us to do the work for you is not respectful of other SO users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first value, use a NumericUpDown instead of a TextBox.  This will restrict it to Integer values and allow you specify a Minimum value (0) and a Maximum value (255).  The Button can make use of the Random class and a simple Counter variable.  Display the number of clicks in a Label as this value probably isn't meant to be changed by the user:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        NumericUpDown1.Minimum = 0
        NumericUpDown1.Maximum = 255
        Label1.Text = "Clicks: 0"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Static R As New Random
        Static Counter As Integer = 0
        NumericUpDown1.Value = R.Next(NumericUpDown1.Maximum + 1)
        Counter = Counter + 1
        Label1.Text = "Clicks: " & Counter
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Idle_Mind I would like to thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to know why is it forceing it to be NumericUpDown1.Value = R.Next(CInt(NumericUpDown1.Maximum + 1))

Comment: No other reason than the question was vague.  You could go directly to a TextBox with `TextBox1.Text = R.Next(256)`.